# how to perform 10 iterations for the generated SHA-256 string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do encrypt input using SHA-256 in other words i am planning to hash using SHA-25.Here's the code that i found to do this but my requirment is to do 10 iteration for the genarated SHA string right now using this code does only 1 iteration how do i do that?

```
<form action="#" method="post">
 Enter a text:<br/>
 <input type="text" name="strex" id="strex" size="20" /> <button id="cryptstr">Encrypt</button><br/>
 SHA256 hash string:<br/>
<input type="text" name="strcrypt" id="strcrypt" size="33" />
</form>
```

Here is the link to complete code https://jsfiddle.net/arty3z8z/

Comment: what you will do then ??

Comment: Will pass the generated SHA-256 string to service as a input.

Comment: Why do you need to iterate SHA245 10 times? It neither adds appreciably time nor adds more security.